# Selectize.js get more data in "onItemAdd" callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, selectize.js

**TL;DR**

To make it clearer, I want to have access to ALL the data in the selected JSON object inside the `onItemAdd` function. Right now I only have access to `_id` and `name` via the config variables.

---

Ok, so I have a working Selectize.js function grabbing a JSON object from my server and creating the select options.

What I want to know is, can I get anymore data from the existing JSON object inside the "onItemSelect" callback?

The only data I can get directly is the `value` as specified in the config, which in this case is the "_id" and the `$item` which i assume is form the `labelField` in the config, in this case is the `name` form the JSON data.

How can I get more data than that for the selected item? You see in the render object I use the variable `item.sku`, how can I access the `sku` variable in the "onItemAdd" callback?

the data form the server is a json array:

```
[
  { _id: 'abcd1234', name: 'Sample', sku: '00123' }, 
  { _id: 'efgh5678', name: 'Sample2', sku: '00124' }
]
```

My function

```
// setup select box to add new products to list
$('#buyingGroupAddProducts').selectize({
  valueField: '_id',
  labelField: 'name',
  searchField: 'name',
  options: [],
  create: false,
  closeAfterSelect: true,
  render: {
    option: function(item, escape) {
      return '<div>'+ escape(item.sku) + ': ' + escape(item.name) + '</div>';
    }
  },
  load: function(query, callback) {
    if (!query.length) return callback();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/buying/products-search',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        q: query
      },
      error: function() {
        callback();
      },
      success: function(res) {
        callback(res);
      }
    });
  },
  onItemAdd: function(value, $item) {

    // DO the thing
    console.log($item);

  }
});
```

SelectizeJS site: http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Comment: have you sovled this? I am looking for answer too.

Comment: @neobie I did, but not with Selectize. I can't remember which project I used this for, one I built my own plugin from scratch, the other I used http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/

Answer (score 1):

a hack to solve your problem : inside `onItemAdd` function you can access all your JSON : `this.options` gives you all the selectize options, so now you have the value and the complete JSON, you can easily find back the item in your json that corresponds to the value selected. I can complete my answer if you provide a use case in [plunker](https://plnkr.co).